# How to stop logged in user from clicking back button and going to login page

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, back

So I noticed the fact that after a user logs in then clicks on the back button it returns them back to the login page. How do I make it so that it doesn't do that?? The logout version of the code I found to stop clicking the back button to go to secured page from happening doesn't seem to apply to the login problem I'm experiencing.

Here's the code I added to constructor and it seems to have stopped logout from using back to return to secured page:

```
parent::__construct();
        $this->output->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
        $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->driver('cache');
    }
```

Also added a $this->cache->clean() at logout

Comment: check the log in session in the `login` page and redirect to the users `home` until he `logout` from the system.

Comment: how does that work?? I mean your pressing the back button so I think you're not passing through the functions in your controller to validate session. Sorry if I'm wrong it's my first time dealing with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample codes or you, In your login controller check the exist login session.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ();
    $valid_login = $this->session->userdata ( 'valid_login' );
    if ($valid_login == 1) {
        redirect ( base_url('homeController') );
    }
    return true;
}

public function checklogin() {
    $name = $this->input->post ( 'username' );
    $pass = $this->input->post ( 'password' );

    $this->load->model ( 'loginModel' );

    if ($this->loginModel->login ( $name, $pass )) {
        $this->session->set_userdata ( 'username', $name );
        $this->session->set_userdata ( 'valid_login', 1 );
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now in the home controller check for the login session else log out and redirect to the login page like bellow.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ();

    $valid_login = $this->session->userdata ( 'valid_login' );
    if ($valid_login == "")
        redirect ( 'loginController' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this..

```
 function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
    //$this->load->model('model_session');
    $this->load->model('model_vanshaval');
    $this->load->model('model_session');
  if($this->model_session->check_logged()==FALSE){
 redirect('welcome');
}
```

you could write this constructor in welcome controller to check whether user is logged in or not..